# Calculating form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this calculating form works extremely well for my client up some one went and put in to the percentage box 0.93 and it showed to wrong amount.

In the website: 10  x  10  x  15  x 0.93  =  13.95

Has to be: 10  x  10  x  15  x 0.93  =  1.395

I have no idea what to change in the javascript to get the full stop in the right place

This is the script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate() {
    var fields = [], i = 1, el, val, whole, total;
    for (i; i < 5; ++i) {
        el = document.getElementById('el' + i); val = el.value;
        if((whole = i < 3) && /\./.test(val) || isNaN(Number(val))) {
            alert("Please enter only " + (whole? 'whole ' : '') +    "numbers\nfor " + (el.value = el.defaultValue));
            el.focus();
            el.select();
            return;
        }
        fields.push(val);
    }
    total = (fields[0] * fields[1] * fields[2])*fields[3]/100;
    document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML = "Total: " + total;
}
</script></head>

<body>
<form action="#" onSubmit="calculate(); return false;">
    <label>Days: <input type="text" id="el1" value="10"></label>
    <label>Taxis: <input type="text" id="el2"  value="10"></label>
    <label>Perdiem: <input type="text" id="el3" value="15"></label>
    <label>Discount: <input type="text" id="el4" value="93"></label>
    <div id="calculate">Total:</div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I will appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

`total = (fields[0] * fields[1] * fields[2])*fields[3]/1000`

instead of:

`total = (fields[0] * fields[1] * fields[2])*fields[3]/100`

Comment: I did not try this one just played with the rest of the coding.


**Thanks this will work**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getFormattedNumber(number, decimals) {
    return number.toFixed(decimals);
}
```

It returns a string of the number, fixed to the decimal places you specify.

This is what it will do:

```
For 2dp: getFormattedNumber(number, 2):
number:              return:
13.435345345         13.44
10.3435345           10.34

For 3dp: getFormattedNumber(number, 3):
number:
9.556622             9.557
```

etc.

So you can work with the proper numbers, and use that to fix the decimal places.

Comment: p.s. use `parseFloat(string)` to get a number back from the string output of this function